# Faces appear to have an underlying mesh in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Using blender 2.79 here. One of my file has this issue where faces appear to have an underlying mesh in edit mode, even with a freshly added cube. Any clue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's looks like [Z-culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering#Z-culling) issue when clipping distance is too big. In this case you may:

1. Reduce the distance between start and end of clipping (in <kbd>N</kbd>-panel):

   [image]
2. Try 2.79b or [2.79 master daily build](https://builder.blender.org/download/), it have not this problem
3. Do not pay attention to it - it is not affects on render.